# Use `super` function into `partialmethod`

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the magic python `partialmethod` functool. But this partial method must referenced a function from my parent class.
Consider the test code below :

```py
from functools import partialmethod

class MyResource:
    @staticmethod
    def load_resource(id):
        print(f"Loding a new resource ! {id}")
        return MyResource(id)


class CachedDataMixin:
    _cache = {}
    def _get_resource(self, source_cls, id):
        if source_cls not in self._cache or id not in self._cache[source_cls]:
            resource = source_cls.load_resource(id)
            self._cache.setdefault(source_cls, {})[id] = resource
        return self._cache[source_cls][id]

class MyClass(CachedDataMixin):
   _get_my_resource = partialmethod(_get_resource, MyResource)
   def run(self):
       obj1 = _get_my_resource(12345)
       obj2 = _get_my_resource(12345)
       return obj1, obj2

MyClass().run()
```

When I tried to run this code, I get an error message `NameError: name '_get_resource' is not defined` on `_get_my_resource = partialmethod(_get_resource, MyResource)`.

I tried use `partialmethod(self._get_resource, MyResource)` or `partialmethod(super()._get_resource, MyResource)` but it doesn't work.

I found a workaround redeclaring the `_get_resource` function into `MyClass` but this solution seems very ugly for me :

```py
class MyClass(CachedDataMixin):
    def _wrapped_get_resource(self, source_cls, id):
        return super()._get_resource(source_cls, id)
   _get_my_resource = partialmethod(_wrapped_get_resource, MyResource)
   ...
```

Is anyone has a pretty solution to not write my ugly workaround ?
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several things here:

1. You can't reference `CachedDataMixin._get_resource` in class attribute, because it's not defined within class itself.  Instances of `MyClass` will have it, but class objects differ from instance objects.
2. You can't use `self` for the same reason: it's defined only within methods, and refers to an instance object.
3. `super()` works dynamically when called from methods (and uses instances), so no luck with using it in class *attribute* either.
4. You can hardcode class name here:

   ```py
   _get_my_resource = partialmethod(CachedDataMixin._get_resource, MyResource)
   ```

   I would personally go with more explicit option:

   ```py
   def _get_my_resource(self, id_):
       return super()._get_resource(MyResource, id_)
   ```
5. Then, after a couple of fixes like these:

   ```py
   # you forgot to call a method using `self`
   obj1 = self._get_my_resource(12345)
   ```

   and

   ```py
   class MyResource:
       # otherwise you can't do `MyResource(12345)`
       def __init__(self, id_):
           self.id = id_
   ```

It has finally worked ("loading resource" only once with no errors).

Comment: Your point #4 seems the best solution for my problem.
Thanks for your help